# Writing Pip packages -- how to deal with downloading/processing large external datasets?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, dataset, physics

EDIT: if anyone is finding this at a later date, the package [pooch](https://www.fatiando.org/pooch/latest/index.html) is perfect for this.

---

I'm writing a pip package to work with / analyze various Mars data (I expect most users will operate within Jupyter notebooks) as a supplement to my research paper. Researchers in this field are notoriously atrocious with software practices (most researchers don't even publish code, so newcomers have to reinvent everything themselves), so I'm trying to make some easy-to-use packages for standardizing analysis. I'm looking for advice/wisdom for implementing some features.

Some context for the underlying data I'm working with: One raw data file (229 KB) can be processed into one ready-to-use dataset (100 MB) within 90 seconds. We have 21,000 raw data files (total 5 GB). Of course I can't include all of this in my library, and I want to account for users possibly only using a handful of raw data files.

I've broken my ideas for downloading/processing data into three parts below:

[I'll be referring to the package as `mars` throughout this post. ]

## Question 1

My current approach is to let the user describe the desired dataset, after which the corresponding raw data file is downloaded from Google Drive using [gdown](https://pypi.org/project/gdown/). If it matters, I'm using Google Drive because my university grants unlimited storage and certain [scripting abilities](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/88769/get-share-link-of-multiple-files-in-google-drive-to-put-in-spreadsheet) allow me to quickly get an exact download link (I can see how this may be a reproducibility issue, so I'll upload an archive to Zenodo). However, I'm unsure of where the intended user would store this data locally. My current idea is to have a `setDataPath()` function for users to provide a path on their system (either absolute or relative -- the latter would be more reproducible) where either (a) a new directory is initialized with a readme/identifier and data will henceforth be downloaded there, or (b) a pre-existing directory exists [it must contain an identifier, verifying it was produced by my package] and already-generated data can be used. This allows users to simply delete the data folder if it's taking up too much space or if certain data products are no longer needed (I will provide user-friendly methods to do this). Usage might look like this:

```py
import mars

mars.setDataPath(absolute_path='/home/mars_data/')
# mars.setDataPath(relative_path=('..', 'mars_data/')) # alternate method


from mars import SomeSatellite, SomeRover

SomeSatellite.loadDataset(dataset_name='...') # downloads+processes to `mars_data/Satellite/'
SomeRover.loadDataset(dataset_name='...') # downloads+processes to `mars_data/Rover/`

SomeRover.deleteDataset(dataset_name='...') # deletes `mars_data/Rover/`

mars.deleteAllData() # clears `mars_data/`
```

I'm worried this is clunky/contrived as I'm coming up with it from scratch. I'm open to any feedback.

---

## Question 2

Going back to my paragraph about "some context for the data" -- I'm not sure if the processing from raw data to ready-to-use data should be done user-side with a method like `loadData` (check if ready-to-use data is available locally, if not then download the raw file and process it); or if I should provide a Jupyter notebook that does this. The former sounds better in almost every way (reproducible, less dependencies, user-friendly), but users might be annoyed by long upfront download/processing times while they're in the midst of data analysis. I might just provide a `loadDataset(dataset_name='demo')` option that downloads some pre-processed data quickly from Google Drive.

---

## Question 3

I want to provide some Jupyter notebooks alongside my library for tutorials and custom dataset generation (in case users want to change how the raw data is processed into ready-to-use data). My idea is to make it so `mars tutorial` in CLI makes `notebooks/` in your current directory, which contains everything you might need. My question is should these notebooks be included in the package and copied upon request, downloaded from Google Drive, or cloned from a GitHub repository under the same organization as `mars`?

---

Thanks! This is my first question so apologies in advance if something is wrong.